# Understanding a proof related to continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Suppose that $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is some continuous function with $f(y)>0$ for some $y\in X$. I read in a proof that says

> Since $f$ is continuous, there are an open neighborhood $U$ of $y$ and an $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\geq \delta$ for $x\in X$.

I do not understand why they exist, could you explain what was going on? The way I almost understand is:

1. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists open set $U$ containing $y$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in U$. I can't see how this is reached by the definition of continuity ...
2. Since $f>0$ on $U$ by 1), we choose $\delta>0$ so small that $f(x)\geq \delta$ for all $x\in U$. Is this allowed? If so, why?

Comment: Take $U = f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ and $U= f^{-1} (\delta, \infty)$ respectively, where $0<\delta< f(y)$.

Comment: To see (1), consider the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity. Choose $\epsilon$ to be $\frac{f(y)}{2}$. Then there is some $\delta$ such that whenever $x$ is within $\delta$ units of $y$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{f(y)}{2}$. Therefore in the neighbourhood defined by this $\delta$, $f(x)$ will be greater than $0$

Comment: @masiewpao $\epsilon-\delta$ definition works only for metric spaces.

Comment: I assume you mean "$f(x) \geq \delta$ for all $x \in U$", not "for all $x \in X$".

Comment: @ArcticChar I would have sworn I thought it had a real analysis tag when I first read the problem... my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\delta = \frac{f(y)}{2}$. Then $(\delta, \infty)$ is an open set. By the definition of continuity (for a general topological space), $U = f^{-1}((\delta, \infty))$ is open. And clearly by definition, $y \in U$ since $f(y) > f(y) / 2 = \delta$. And for all $x \in U$, we have $f(x) > \delta$ and thus $f(x) \geq \delta$.